# How to force download zip file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, download

I am trying to create a simple digital store web application using codeigniter.
I would like to use the force download helper function so that the real url of the file will not be known by the user.
I tried following the documentation in the codeignter - it works but the file get corrupted.

Here is my code

```
//* Get the website name
                $site = $this->Settings_model->getApllicationInfo();
                $sitename = $site->set_site_name;

                //* Prepare file for downloading

                $filename = $sitename.'-'.$item_info->item_id.'-'.$item_info->item_name;
                $locate = './static/files/zips/'.$file;
                force_download($locate, $filename);
```

It downloads the file but it get broken please help me or give me any other suggestion I can use.

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/download_helper.html?highlight=force_download#force_download - take a look at the section _If you set the second parameter to NULL and $filename is an existing, readable file path, then its content will be read instead._ - it pretty much tells you everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below function to download the file

```
function auto_download($path, $name) {
  if(is_file($path))  {
    if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) { ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off'); }

    $this->load->helper('file');

    $mime = get_mime_by_extension($path);

    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0'); 
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime ($path)).' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: private',false);
    header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($name).'"'); 
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($path));
    header('Connection: close');
    readfile($path);
    exit();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using file extension on the filename you supply for the first argument to `force_download()`. Because `Codeigniter` uses `MIME-type`. I hope it will work for you